# AJAX Response In PHP

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am using Ajax in my PHP but the issue is that my For each loop is not waiting for response of AJAX Call
I tried Promises functions also but it doesn't work for me.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is that you are using synchronous to complete the task.
All you need to do is avoid using the Sync call.

```
 $.ajax({
              url: "file.php",
              data: "test",
              type: "POST",
              async: false,
              success: function(data) {
                alert("Success");
              }
        });
```